# Pass parameter with spaces to CMake ExternalProject_Add BUILD_COMMAND

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile bzip2 in Linux utilizing CMake's `ExternalProject_Add(...)` command.

However, in order to cross-compile libbzip, you must modify some of the Makefile macros to execute the build. Here is my current cross compile variable:

```
set(bzlib_CROSS CC=${CROSS_PREFIX}gcc AR=${CROSS_PREFIX}ar RANLIB=${CROSS_PREFIX}ranlib LDFLAGS=-L${bzlib_MINGW_SRC}/lib CFLAGS=-Wall -Winline -O2 -g -I${bzlib_MINGW_SRC}/include)
```

This variable is then used for the build command

```
set(bzlib_BUILD make ${bzlib_CROSS} PREFIX=${DEPENDENCY_DIR})
```

CMake errors because it is trying to pass -O2, -g, etc. to `make`, which of course doesn't work, but when I try to add quotes around the `CFLAGS` variable it says

```
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wall -Winline -O2 -g -I/long/path/here/include'
```

Is it possible to set a Makefile macro with spaces in it using CMake's `BUILD_COMMAND`? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out...I needed to split the quoted string into its own variable like this

```
set(bzlib_CFLAGS "-Wall -Winline -O2 -g -I${bzlib_MINGW_SRC}/include")
set(bzlib_CROSS CC=${CROSS_PREFIX}gcc AR=${CROSS_PREFIX}ar RANLIB=${CROSS_PREFIX}ranlib LDFLAGS=-L${bzlib_MINGW_SRC}/lib CFLAGS=${bzlib_CFLAGS})
```

This worked!

Comment: An inline "CFLAGS=-Wall -Winline -O2 -g -I${bzlib_MINGW_SRC}/include" with double quotes around the whole thing would also be equivalent to the construct you arrived at...

Comment: Good to know! CMake is awesome =)