# Cross compile stunnel

Tags: linux, makefile, cmake, arm, cross-compiling

I am having difficulties with cross compiling stunnel for an ARM device.
Cross compiling OpenSSL was done via this CMake project: http://www.valvers.com/open-software/projects/openssl-cmake/ and it runs successfully on the target device.

The CMake toolchain file I use when compiling OpenSSL:

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   /home/elias/toolchains/axotec/3.4.1/bin/arm-linux-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /home/elias/toolchains/axotec/3.4.1/bin/arm-linux-g++)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  /home/elias/toolchains/axotec/3.4.1/arm-linux /home/elias/toolchains/axotec/3.4.1/library-for-ramdisk )
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

My question is how do I cross compile stunnel in a similar fashion? I'm struggling with passing stunnel makefile the whole sysroot dir just like in the cmake toolchain file `SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  /home/elias/toolchains/axotec/3.4.1/arm-linux /home/elias/toolchains/axotec/3.4.1/library-for-ramdisk )`

My atempts include, after running the configure, rewriting the makefile CFLAGS with --sysroot= but where to put the second folder?(library-for-arm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General idea:

The openssl-cmake project uses CMake build infrastructure. Hence just specifying the toolchain worked for you. I looked at stunnel source code and they use the traditional GNU Autotools for the build infrastructure which means you cannot use cmake directly on that project. (./configure && make && make install)

You would have to use ExternalProject_Add to compile stunnel using cmake.
Take a look at the following links for more information.

- http://www.kitware.com/media/html/BuildingExternalProjectsWithCMake2.8.html
- http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/ExternalProject.html

Also this:

- [Pass parameter with spaces to CMake ExternalProject_Add BUILD_COMMAND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144357/pass-parameter-with-spaces-to-cmake-externalproject-add-build-command)

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.2)
include(ExternalProject)

set(CROSS_INFO CC=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} CXX=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} AR=${CMAKE_AR})


ExternalProject_Add(
    stunnel
    URL http://www.stunnel.org/downloads/stunnel-5.17.tar.gz
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND <SOURCE_DIR>/configure --host=powerpc --with-sysroot=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH} ${CROSS_INFO}
)
```

**Additional info:**
I tried to run the above project locally on my system and I ended up spending an hour debugging it with the powerpc toolchain file I have. There is some problem with the configure script of stunnel. The way sysroot and with-ssl dir are being calculated is kind of not correct. You might have to mess with the configure file to get the cross compile to work. But the general idea is specified above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will certainly look into it